# Write core logic in golang and UI in Swift?

Tags: macos, go

Would Mac App Store accept an OSX application, if I write core logic / utilities in golang, while write UI in Swift? The UI might spawn a process running golang application and communicated it with either stdin/stdout or some kind of json RPC.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Thanks for the reply. I was talking about OSX application. Would it be OK then?

Comment: Ah, OS X? I believe so, then.

Answer (score 0):

If you include the Go part as a library then it shouldn't be a problem. A separate program might be more tricky.